# How to create a view which shows me items in a list that are assigned to a group I belong to. (without SharePoint designer)

Tags: list-view

I have a list in my SharePoint site that has a column - `"Assigned to"`. this field is of type `"Person or Group"`. I want to create a view for this list which shows those items which:

1. are assigned to me OR
2. are assigned to a SharePoint group I belong to.

Part 1 is fairly straightforward and I have been able to create a filter for the view such that `"Assigned to" = [Me]`.

I am finding it a bit of a challenge to implement part 2 without the sharepoint designer feature. Is there any workaround for this?

If not, what is the way to proceed?

Comment: Last time I tried, even if Assigned To was a group, you could use `Assigned To is equal to [Me]` and it would filter properly regardless if it was a group or an individual user. But that was about 8 years ago so I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to edit the CAML query and make use to Membership property.

As per my understanding you can only do this via SPD.